# SumProduct with division?

Tags: excel

I have 2 columns that span across many rows. What I need to do is calculate the percentage of each row and then add them. Setup is something like:

```
ColA      ColB
5         5
10        
          10
3         7
```

The total for ColA, should be calculated like (5/(5+5))+(10/(5+5))+(0/(0+10))+(3/(3+7)). I have a formula which works in:

`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A1000)/(A2:A1000+B2:B1000))`

The problem is that if there are blank values in both rows, then it gives the #DIV/0 error because you can't divide by 0.  How would I write the formula to exclude rows where both are blank?

**EDIT:**
Some actual data and expected values are:

```
ColA      ColB
40      
          40
35      
          35
35      
          35
          35
35      
17.5      17.5
          40
40      
          40
40      
7.5       28.5
36      
          36
36      
36
```

When totaling ColA, should be ***9.7***
When totaling ColB, should be ***8.3***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an "array formula" like this:

`=SUM(IFERROR((A2:A1000)/(A2:A1000+B2:B1000),0))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

That works in excel 2007 or later versions

see screenshot

[image]

Comment: Although that works in the example, if I add other values such as 10,20, it ignores them altogether.  I tried putting the SUMPRODUCT in the first parameter of the IFERROR as well, but it still doesn't calculate properly either.

Comment: I set up the same data and got `9.7` and `8.3` as you suggest, using exactly the formula above - did you "array enter" it? If done correctly you will get curly braces like { and } around the formula. I added a screenshot

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize I had to do something with the formula.  Works great! Thanks!

Comment: @L42 - re downvote, sorry that was me - by mistake! I tried to reverse but it wouldn't let me (I was on mobile) - if you re-instate your answer I'll try to reverse